# No property findAllEntries found for type Entry

Tags: java, spring

I don't know why Spring doesn't like my code:

I have `Entry.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entries")
public class Entry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;
}
```

`EntryDao.java`:

```
public interface EntryDao extends JpaRepository<Entry, Long> {
    List<Entry> findAllEntries();
}
```

`EntryService.java`:

```
@Service
public interface EntryService {

    List<Entry> findAllEntries();

}
```

`EntryServiceImpl.java`:

```
public class EntryServiceImpl implements EntryService {
    private EntryDao entryDao;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Entry> findAllEntries()  {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Entry> entries = session.createQuery("from entries").list();
        return entries;
    }
}
```

This code gives me an error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entryDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllEntries found for type Entry!

I don't understand how to handle this error and why this error occurs.

Comment: put `@Service` on implementation

Comment: @Ramanlfc nope, didn't help

Comment: where is `EntryDao` implementation

Comment: Why are you accessing database in your service class? it should be done at dao layer.

Comment: JPA is unable to resolve your method `List<Entry> findAllEntries();`. And by the way JPA already has a method `findAll()` that gives you all the rows in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AbdullahWasi said, just use the existing `findAll()` method from SpringData for your code. You might want to place a `@Transactional` annotation in your code, but that depends on your transaction boundaries.

Just remove your custom method from your Dao.

```
public interface EntryDao extends JpaRepository<Entry, Long> {
}
```

And use the default spring data `findAll`

```
@Transactional
public class EntryServiceImpl implements EntryService {
    private EntryDao entryDao;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Entry> findAllEntries()  {
        return entryDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The root cause you got the exception is that you're against the convention/rules to declare/create queries in Spring Data JPA.

[The official docs of Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#repositories) mentioned that:

> The goal of Spring Data repository abstraction is to significantly reduce the amount of boilerplate code required to implement data access layers for various persistence stores.

The central interface of abstraction is `Repository`, to manage your entity, you need to declare your own interface of `Repository` and JPA will help you to create proxy instances for those interfaces. There're already some base `Repositories` like `CrudRepository` or `PagingAndSortingRepository` to provide basic functionalities as you can tell from their names, so by extending those basic ones, you'll have many basic methods. To define more specific access methods, you need to follow the ways JPA provided to create queries:

- Define method in your interface following the method name convention
- Use @Query annotation to define it manually

For the first method, [the docs of Query Create](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) has detailed clarification, here's some key idea:

> The mechanism strips the prefixes find…By, read…By, query…By, count…By, and get…By from the method and starts parsing the rest of it. The introducing clause can contain further expressions such as a Distinct to set a distinct flag on the query to be created. However, the first By acts as delimiter to indicate the start of the actual criteria. At a very basic level you can define conditions on entity properties and concatenate them with And and Or

Simply speaking, JPA will parse the method name and try to find the related property to create query criteria for you.

Now let's have a look at your code, if you just want to retrieve all of your entities, you don't need to define your own method, there's already `findAll` methods pre-defined, if you want to retrieve entities based on `text` content, it's supposed to look like:

```
Entity findByText(String text)
```

but your method `findAllEntites` just don't match any rules, so JPA throws such an error message to you.