# No property saveAll found for type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

I recently started using *ReactiveCouchbaseRepository* (spring-data-couchbase - 3.0.0.M2, spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.0.0.M2) in one of our projects.

I referred to [unpublished doc from here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reactiverepository.adoc) and setup the project but I am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dummyRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property saveAll found for type Dummy!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1717) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:233) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
```

Here is the relevant information about setting up my project.

@Maven

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
```

@java

```
//Repository class
public interface DummyRepository extends ReactiveCouchbaseSortingRepository<Dummy, String> {
}

//Model class
public class Dummy {

@Id
private final String id;

@Field
private final String name;

@Field
private final String address;

...
}

//Java config class
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCouchbaseRepositories
public class CouchbaseDatabaseConfig extends AbstractReactiveCouchbaseConfiguration {

...
}
```

Now, i did go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467894/no-property-found-for-type-custom-spring-data-repository) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123443/no-property-findallentries-found-for-type-entry) but here i have no custom method written in the *DummyRepository* class.

*Note that* when I change from *ReactiveCouchbaseSortingRepository* to *CouchbaseRepository*, the things works fine.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Add @EnableCouchbaseRepositories on Configuration class and @Document() on your Dummy class, and check it. Let me know if its work

Comment: Naah, that doesn't work either!

Answer (score 1):

It seems we just need to add the following dependency to have *saveAll* implementation in.

`<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
</dependency>`

ps : thanks to *Subhashni Balakrishnan* to have answered it on [couchbase forums - here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/propertyreferenceexception-no-property-saveall-found-for-type-dummy/13427/2)

Answer (score 0):

You should Add @Query on you method otherwise, the jpa will treat it as a property